# React CSV download is not in CSV format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv

I'm using react CSV to convert my data to excel CSV.
However when I use the react CSV library to download my data in CSV,
 I get this file:

[image: The downloaded file]

The content of this file is comma seperated so good to add in CSV.
So why isn't my file in `.CSV` format?

This is my code for CSVLink:

```
<CSVLink data={dataex} filename={"belhistorie.csv"} className="btn btn-primary">
    Download me
</CSVLink>
```

This is my dataex object:

```
const dataex = [{
     CallID: '247279',
     OriginationName: '',
     DestinationName: 'destination',
     OriginationNumber: '+31555776005',
     DestinationNumber: '+31410008993',
     Calltime: '00:17',
     StartTime: '06-12-2018 08:00',
     EndTime: '06-12-2018 08:00',
     Type: 'incoming',
     State: 'Connected'
},{
     CallID: '247280',
     OriginationName: 'person1',
     DestinationName: 'person2',
     OriginationNumber: '+31777779314',
     DestinationNumber: '803',
     Calltime: '00:54',
     StartTime: '06-12-2018 08:00',
     EndTime: '06-12-2018 08:00',
     Type: 'incoming',
     State: 'Connected'
}];
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. It seems the file format is proper CSV, but that it's not getting the right name?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst check the image, the file is not csv format, only the contents

Comment: Check this out https://codesandbox.io/s/w2kowjl245 tried testing it and it is working.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work on my localhost. I'm not using node.js Im using CDN to include those libraries and I also have a react table included in the file

Answer (score 2):

From above, adding `.csv` to the end worked. The issue only occured on chrome, Firefox already knew it as a `.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been over a year ago from the post, but I am facing the same problem on my react-web-app.

Maybe this comment will help you: 
https://github.com/react-csv/react-csv/issues/46#issuecomment-542537417

Apparently this issue only occurs on Windows users (I'm developing on MacOS -.csv extension works fine- and my window-using-boss tells me about this bug)
The basic procedure, is to import a library called "react-device-detect"
and create a logic using 'osVersion' or 'osName' method from that library, making an OS detector statement and manually add the ".csv" string to the property "filename" of "CSVLink".

By the way, this is my first "contributing" comment! Hope this helps!